# Translator Dictionary Android App

Tags: android

We've been working a translator of English words into a native language. It's working for every word we input. But we would like to put a Warning message if the input word is not found. Please we need help in order to finish this project. Thank you very much. Here's are code for the "Word not found" function:

```
String xmeaning =(String) map.get(xtranslate);
xeng.setText(xmeaning);
if (xtranslate.equals("")){
   xeng.setText("NOT FOUND!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show `AlertDialog` like :

```
if (xtranslate.equals("")){
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Warnning")
                .setMessage("NOT FOUND!")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .create().show();
}
```